# How can I use WHERE id IN (@a_varchar_variable) in SQL Server stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In my table `id` column's datatype is `int`.

And I have a list of items' ids to be selected.

So, here is some piece of my code:

```
DECLARE @user_list
SELECT @user_list=(
SELECT user_list
FROM sometable
WHERE rowNum=xxx
);
SELECT *
FROM anotherTable
WHERE user_id IN(@user_list)
```

but it doesn't work, the error msg like :

> *can't convert varchar to int*

Thanks!

Comment: Is `user_list` a comma separated string?

Comment: yes, it's a comma separated string in a varchar(MAX) column

Comment: The `WHERE id IN (...)` expects a **list of (several) `int`** values, while you're passing in a **single string** that contains a list of int... that is not the same thing and they're not compatible. You need to **extract** those ints from the string and pass them in as a list of `int`

Comment: i see, but i'm wondering how can i achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can Create a Split function and that will be use when you want.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(   
    @List nvarchar(max),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(1)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table (
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Value nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
    Begin 
        Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
        Select 
            Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
        Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
    End 

    Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
    Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

    Return
END
```

after that you can call the function in your query as below.

```
SELECT * FROM anotherTable WHERE user_id IN(dbo.split(@user_list,','))
```

Otherwise, you have to use dynamic query.

Comment: SELECT * FROM anotherTable WHERE user_id IN(SELECT Value FROM dbo.split(@user_list,',')) is right! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks bro  It found helpful to me !!

Answer (score 0):

you can use dynamic sql

```
exec('
SELECT *
FROM anotherTable
WHERE user_id IN('+@user_list+')')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make `@user_list` a table variable, you can join or filter against it like any other table

```
 declare @user_list table (id int)
 insert @user_list(id)
 SELECT user_list 
 FROM sometable 
 WHERE rowNum=xxx 


 SELECT * 
 FROM anotherTable 
 WHERE user_id IN(select Id from @user_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a table variable, which allows you to add normal word into a variable:

```
DECLARE @user_list AS TABLE (user_id int NOT NULL);

INSERT @user_list
SELECT user_list
FROM sometable
WHERE rowNum=xxx;

SELECT *
FROM anotherTable
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM @user_list)
```